# Filter/Subset data in R to give column names for each value less than 1

Tags: r, filter, subset

I am faced with some very large data sets (too large for excel to handle). One dataset contains the distances from various areas in the country to various stations:

`stdist`:

```
---  AREA1 AREA2 AREA3
STA1  -      -     -
STA2  -      -     -
STA3  -      -     -
```

I am firstly looking to only get figures where the distance from a given area to a station is less than 1km. I have tried `stdist[stdist<1]`, but this just displays a list of numbers with no reference to the area/station they relate to:

```
 STA1  AREA1  AREA2  AREA3
 STA2  AREA4  AREA5
 STA3  AREA6  AREA7  AREA8  AREA20
```

The aim is to make a list of all of the areas within 1km of each station, and look these up in another spreadsheet to give the employment in the area within 1km of the station.

Any advice on this next step would also be appreciated. Primarily I am looking for a list of each station and the areas within 1km of it.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The second dataset has a list of area names, as are used in the column headings of `stdist`, along with employment data. For example if these areas 1:4 are within 1km of station 1:

```
STATION 1:
Area Name   Employment
Area 1      200
Area 2      550
Area 3      1020
Area 4      420
```

For example. The aim is to match the area names gathered from the first step, with the employment in these areas.

The output I require is:

```
        Sum of Employment within 1km
Station     2190
```

Hopefully this helps you in answering my question.

**EDIT 2**

Have tried akrun's latest solution and here is what I get:

```
station1 <- read.csv("MSOA employ.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(station1)
##[1] 7194    2
stdist <- read.csv("MSOAtoSTAT.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(stdist)
##[1] 2891 1972

colnm1 <- read.csv("msoahead.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(colnm1)
##[1]    1 1972
rownm1 <- read.csv("stathead.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(rownm1)
##[1] 2891    1

stdist <- as.matrix(stdist)
rownames(stdist) <- rownm1$V1
indx <- stdist <=1

val1 <- indx
m1 <- match(colnames(stdist), station1$NAME)
v1 <- station1$Employment[m1]
val1[] <- v1[col(indx)] 
val1[!indx] <- NA
sumVal <- rowSums(val1, na.rm=TRUE)
head(sumVal)

#             Brora Station             Thurso Station Georgemas Junction Station 
#                         0                          0                          0 
#       Scotscalder Station               Wick Station          Helmsdale Station 
#                         0                          0                          0

tail(sumVal)

#  Long Eaton Station Langley Mill Station     Peartree Station        Derby Station 
#                   0                    0                    0                    0 
#    Duffield Station       Belper Station 
#                   0                    0
```

Comment: You may have to use `which(stdist<1, arr.ind=TRUE)` and get the column and row index.

Comment: akrun, thanks, this solution gives me some of what I wanted although I'm unsure how to proceed to the second part of my question from these results. (looking up employment of each listed area from a separate data frame)

Comment: It is not clear how your second dataset looks like.  So, it would be better to show some few lines of second dataset and the expected output.

Comment: I guess the `2190` will only be attained if all the `Areas` in the first dataset is `<1 km` right?  Based on the data provided by Manuel Weinkauf, the sum would be 750?

Comment: Correct, this is indeed what I am looking for. Thank you for your answers, and please see my comment on your answer below.

Comment: Regarding the 2000 stations, are they in separate files?

Comment: No, the stations are within the first datafile. What I have is an array of station names as the row headings, and area names as the columns; with each cell holding the distance between a given station and area.
I want to gather together those areas within 1km of each station, and grab the employment from a seperate data set, which lists the employment against the various area names. 
Finally I wish to sum up the employment within 1km of each station.

Comment: I understand the `stdist` dataset.  But, you also showed a second dataset `STATION 1`.  My question was whether you have 2000 datasets like the one you showed.

Comment: Or do you have a column named `STATION` in the second dataset to match the `STATION` and `AREA` of the first dataset ie. `stdist`.  My understanding was that you wanted the get the sum of `Employment` for each `STATION` separately.  Or is it the total `Employment`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This data set station1 does not exist and was meant to show the sort of output I want to achieve as an intermediate step. So no, I do not have 2000 data sets. The only time `station` appears is in the first data set.

Comment: I wish to get the employment of each station separately. I envisaged doing this by first finding areas within 1km of each station, and then matching these areas to the employments from the second data set.

Comment: I updated the post.  Please check.

Comment: Can I know whether it worked for you?

Comment: akrun - thanks for that, seems to be something going wrong when matching up the columns, the variables m1 and v1 are just arrays of NAs - see my latest edit

Comment: sorry - had copied blindly before and didn't pass `stdist` the `colnm1`. Works perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using stdist from @Manuel Weinkauf's post

```
indx <- stdist <=1
```

If the `Area` and `Name` are in the same order as `stdist` and you wanted to get the sum of `Employment` within 1 km.

```
sum(station1[indx['Station.1',],'Employment'])
 #[1] 750
```

#### Update

It is not very clear what you wanted.  Because the second dataset is not in the same order, we are trying to simulate that with changing the order of the `station1`

```
 set.seed(21)
 stationNew <- station1[sample(4),]
 nm1 <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", colnames(indx)))
 val1 <- indx
 val1[] <- stationNew$Employment[match(nm1, stationNew$Name)][col(indx)]
 val1[!indx] <- NA
 rowSums(val1, na.rm=TRUE)
 #Station.1 Station.2 Station.3 Station.4 
 #    750      1020      1440       620
```

#### Update2

Using the `new datasets`

```
station1 <- read.csv("MSOA employ.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(station1)
#[1] 7194    2
stdist <- read.csv("MSOAtoSTAT.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(stdist)
#[1] 2891 1024

colnm1 <- read.csv("msoahead.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(colnm1)
#[1]    1 1024
rownm1 <- read.csv("stathead.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(rownm1)
#[1] 2891    1

stdist <- as.matrix(stdist)
rownames(stdist) <- rownm1$V1
indx <- stdist <=1
val1 <- indx

m1 <- match(colnames(stdist), station1$NAME)
v1 <- station1$Employment[m1]
val1[] <- v1[col(indx)]
val1[!indx] <- NA
sumVal <- rowSums(val1, na.rm=TRUE)
head(sumVal)
#             Brora Station             Thurso Station 
#                         0                          0 
#Georgemas Junction Station        Scotscalder Station 
#                         0                          0 
#              Wick Station          Helmsdale Station 
#                         0                          0 
tail(sumVal)
#  Long Eaton Station Langley Mill Station     Peartree Station 
#             1900030              2183012              2099062 
#       Derby Station     Duffield Station       Belper Station 
#             2112427              2208312              2272835
```

#### data

```
station1 <- structure(list(Area = c("Area", "Area", "Area", "Area"), Name = 1:4, 
Employment = c(200L, 550L, 1020L, 420L)), .Names = c("Area", 
"Name", "Employment"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: This is so nearly what I am after. Unfortunately the area names from the first data set are not in the same order as those I have employment data for. I also require this sum to be easily computed for all (2000 odd) stations! I suppose I require something comparable to the vlookup function of Excel.

Comment: What does the "\\D+" and "" part of the argument for gsub relate to ?

Comment: @Chris `\\D+` matches all the elements that are not digits and replace that with `''`.  So, in other words, we are extracting the numbers from the colnames and match it against the `Name` column of `stationNew`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6k4d6t8edrud7m7/AADW2paCpuF2YxS_FEYkDtbwa?dl=0 so MSOA employment is our `station1` and MSOAtoSTAT is our`stdist`. I have taken the row and column headings for MSOAtoSTAT into separate worksheets which are what the other two files are.

Comment: @Chris I tried `source` for some time but didn't succeed.  Anyway, so I read the datasets and named the colnames, rownames based on the head data.  It seems to work with the data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have something like in your question, with a variable number of elements for each station, I would think a list might be the best object to store your results:

```
 stdist<-matrix(c(0.4, 1.2, 3.8, 0.1, 0.7, 1.2, 1.8, 3.5, 5.4, 0.1, 0.4, 5.6, 4.4, 2.6, 0.9, 1), 4, 4)
 colnames(stdist)<-paste("Area", 1:4, sep=".")
 rownames(stdist)<-paste("Station", 1:4, sep=".")

 Within<-list()
 for (i in 1:nrow(stdist)) {
     Within[[i]]<-which(stdist[i,]<=1)
 }
 names(Within)<-rownames(stdist)
```

Comment: Thanks, the method works really well. Is there a way I can replace the area names in each part of the list with the employment in that area? I then want to sum the elements of each list to find total employment around the station.